# Backing up SQL Server on Azure Backup Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, backup

I want to backup my SQL Server residing on-premises to Azure using Azure Backup Server (one of the 4 available options i.e. MARS Agent, System Center DPM, Azure Backup Server and Azure IaaS VM Backup).

Is that possible? If yes, then how?

The link I referred to is [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-sql-mabs).

But there is no mention where my SQL Server should reside if Backup Server is in Azure VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a backup of on-premise SQL server by using [Microsoft Azure Backup Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-microsoft-azure-backup).

If you want to protect on-premises workloads, you should install the [Microsoft Azure Backup Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-microsoft-azure-backup) on a Hyper-V VM, a VMware VM, or a physical host. The recommended minimum requirements for the server hardware are two cores, 4 GB RAM and WS 2012.

You can’t protect the on-premises workloads with Microsoft Azure Backup Server [installed on an Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-microsoft-azure-backup#1-choose-an-installation-platform). Microsoft Azure Backup Server running as an Azure virtual machine can only protect workloads that run across multiple Azure cloud services that have the same Azure virtual network and Azure subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an on-premises Azure Backup Server to backup SQL Server.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/backup/backup-azure-sql-mabs